# Get the method on a class or its parents

Tags: python

I need to get the method of a class or, if the class doesn't have a method, the method on its closest parent. 
Another way of saying that is to find the method that would be called by calling a method on an instance of that class.

What's the best way of doing this?

(I'm going to respond to this question with my current solution, which I have a sense is not optimal)

Comment: Can't you just get the method on the class? If the class doesn't have it but the parent class does have it, getting the method from the class will give you the parent method

Comment: @Daenyth - Yes! Not sure why I thought that wasn't the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute lookups on a class will already search base classes, with no extra code needed. Just do:

```
@classmethod
def _init_args(cls):
    return getargspec(cls.__init__).args[1:]
```

If you're using this only on new-style classes (which are the only kind of classes in Python 3), you'll always find an `__init__` method somewhere in the inheritance tree, since `object` has one (and all new-style classes have `object` as their ultimate base class).